# Как отслеживать в AngularJS изменения в реальном времени массива в БД

Tags: angularjs, frontend

**Что хочу сделать:**
Для изменения состояния кнопки необходимо знать присутствует ли id фильма в массиве избранного или нет, в случае если он там есть - кнопка зеленая, если нет- default. Необходимо как-то в реальном времени проверять массив на наличие фильма в нем.

**Непонятно:**
Как реализовать слежение за массивом избранного в реальном времени(хочу ввести вспомогательную переменную с true/false значением на ее основе обновлять состояние кнопки). Просто проверять при загрузке view наличие фильма недостаточно, т.к. пользователю необходимо дать возможность добавить в избранное не выходя из фильма.

Код контроллера:

```
app.controller('VodMovieController', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $timeout, MediaServerService) {
$scope.loadMovieInfo = function () {
    $scope.movieId = parseInt($stateParams.movieId);

    if ($scope.movieId > 0) {

        MediaServerService.GetMoviePoster($scope.movieId)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.poster = response;
            });

        MediaServerService.GetMovieInfo([$scope.movieId])
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.movie = response[0];

                $scope.countries = [];
                $scope.genres = [];

                angular.forEach($scope.movie.countries, function(value, key) {
                    $scope.countries.push(value.name);
                });

                angular.forEach($scope.movie.genres, function(value, key) {
                    $scope.genres.push(value.title);
                });

                $timeout(function () {
                    $$nav.on(null, $('.button'));
                }, 30, false);
            });
    }

};

$scope.setFavorite = function () {
    MediaServerService.GetFavoriteMovie()
        .then(function (response){
            $scope.favorMovie = response;
            console.log($scope.favorMovie);
            if ($scope.favorMovie === undefined){
                MediaServerService.SetFavoriteMovie([$scope.movieId]);
            } else {
                if ($scope.movieId > 0) {
                    if($scope.favorMovie.indexOf($scope.movieId) != -1){
                        $scope.movieIdDel = $scope.movieId;
                    }
                    MediaServerService.UpdateFavoriteMovie([$scope.movieId], [$scope.movieIdDel])
                        .then(function (response){
                });
                $scope.movieIdDel = undefined;
                }
            }
        });
};

$scope.loadMovieInfo();});
```

где,

- **loadMovieInfo**-отвечает за загрузку выбранного ранее фильма.
- **setFavorite** - отвечает за добавление фильма в избранное
- **GetFavoriteMovie** - здесь я запрашиваю массив избранного и далее проверяю массив на пустоту, если true -> **SetFavoriteMovie**,
  false -> **UpdateFavoriteMovie** (если id фильма уже есть в массиве, удаляю его)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется что тебе нужен `watch`

```
$scope.$watch("watcher", function (value) { // watcher - помещаешь объект scope за изменениями которого нужно следить
console.log('watcher was changed');
    });
```

Comment: тогда уж скорее `$watchCollection` (в вопросе речь вроде про массив), но тс вроде хочет знать на клиенте об изменении данных в бд. а в этом случае наверно просто вотчером не обойтись

Comment: Лучше под это создать фабрику с возвращаемым true/false(есть вбазе/нет в базе)?